# How to use Appended columns to eloquent collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to use an eloquent collection with appended columns (Accessors),
but I don't want to append column into the model. 
anyone having suggestion kindly help me.

```
class User extends Authenticatable

{

 /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdmitCardAttribute() {
        if (!$this->relationLoaded('userAdmitCard')) {
            $this->load('userAdmitCard');
        }
        return $this->userAdmitCard->first();
    }
}
```

And repository code, when I retrieving that column then getting "undefined column progress_video" error

```
 public function getAllUsers($inputs) {
        $users = $this->model;

       if (isset($inputs['progress']) && $inputs['progress']) {
            $users = $users->whereBetween('progress_video',
                [$inputs['progress']['from'], $inputs['progress']['to']]);
        }
        return $users;
    }
```

Comment: Accessors don't write data in the database.They simply append data to the in-memory instance. This is only a problem if you try to `save()`. Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: I want to fetch users collection with appended columns, but the problem is I don't want to add $appends column in the user model. @BenSholdice

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$model->append(['attributes'])` in your Query if you dont want  to append it in your model

```
public function getAllUsers($inputs) {
        $users = $this->model->append('ColumName');

       if (isset($inputs['progress']) && $inputs['progress']) {
            $users = $users->whereBetween('progress_video',
                [$inputs['progress']['from'], $inputs['progress']['to']]);
        }
        return $users;
    }
```